# Haskell lexer input and returning list of tokens or error

Tags: haskell, token, lexer, either

Hi i am working on a problem where lexer takes in input string and return either list of tokens or the error. If anyone knows how to go about solving the problem please help. thank you :)

```
lexer :: String -> Either Error [Token]
```

I have gotten problem to be working without using either but can't figure out with either functionality of Haskell. I want left to give an error and right to make list of token with pattern matching with several conditons.

Here's the code that doesn't work:

```
lexar (x:xs) 
  | isSpace x = Main.lexar xs 
  | isDigit x = Right (Literal (show x): Main.lexar xs) 
  | x == '+' = Right (Plus : Main.lexar xs) 
  | x == '-' = Right (Minus : Main.lexar xs) 
  | x == '*' = Right (Mult : Main.lexar xs) 
  | x == '/' = Right (Div : Main.lexar xs) 
  | x == '(' = Right (LeftP : Main.lexar xs) 
  | x == ')' = Right (RightP : Main.lexar xs) 
  | otherwise = Left (error "fail")
```

Comment: @Zack I don’t see any obvious problem with your code… what seems to be the problem with it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**First**, you can't use the `:` operator with the return value of `lexar`.

This version of `lexar` returns an `Either`, which is *not* a list, and therefore cannot be the second argument to operator `:`.

Every time you call `lexar` recursively, it returns you an `Either`, which may be either `Left` or `Right`. If it's `Left`, it contains the error, and you would just pass it up the stack. If it's `Right`, then it contains the result of downstream lexing, and you would prepend the current token to it, then wrap it in a `Right` again before returning. Let's write that down:

```
  | isDigit x = 
      case lexar xs of
          Left err -> Left err
          Right tokens -> Right (Literal (show x) : tokens)
```

Of course, this would become very tedious if you had to write a whole `case` expression for every single token. So instead you could wrap that in a helper function:

```
lexar (x:xs)
  ...
  | isDigit x = prependToken (Literal (show x)) 
  | x == '+' = prependToken Plus
  ...
  where
      prependToken t = 
          case lexar xs of
              Left err -> Left err
              Right tokens -> Right (t : tokens)
```

---

If you're comfortable enough with more abstract concepts, you could also utilize the `Functor` instance of `Either` by using operator `<$>`:

```
lexar (x:xs)
  ...
  | isDigit x = (Literal (show x) :) <$> lexar xs
  | x == '+' = (Plus :) <$> lexar xs
  ...
```

The standard library implementation of operator `<$>` for `Either` will apply the given function to the `Right` value or return the `Left` value unchanged. Essentially it's exactly what my helper function `prependToken` is doing.

---

Finally, when returning a `Left`, don't call the `error` function. This function will crash the program when its result is evaluated, which is not what you want. Just wrap the string in `Left`:

```
  | otherwise = Left "fail"
```